# React router: context.router.push() does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my code:

```
this.props.loginUser(this.state).then(res => {
    let token = res.data.token;
    let decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
    this.context.router.push(`/user/${decodedToken.userid}`)
})
```

I have a login form, and when a user clicks a login button, I want it to take a user to the user page.

However, it does not work and it does not give any error in console. It just stays at the same page, but when I type the path, it will work. So the problem is not my routes or path.

When I change this part: `this.context.router.push(`/user/${decodedToken.userid}`)` to other path like `/signup`, it will work.

Also, when I am in the user page and logged out then logged in, it will work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that `decodedToken.userid` always exists? Can you log it to the console where the push doesn't work?

Comment: @Chris Yes, it always exists. I can log it to the console.